# Write a program that counts in sequential order without using any iterative loops

Tags: java, iteration

Write a program that counts in sequential order when given a start and end value - without using any iterative programing loops, i.e. while, for, do, for-each, etc.

You can assume that both the start and end values will always be positive and that the start value will always be less then the end value.  T

here should only be one method with the following signature:

```
void countUp(int start, int end) {}
```

Here is example output with `start=0` and `end=5`:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Is it valid to flag this kind of users, who only post questions regarding their homework?

Comment: I'd say flag the question and eventually if they persist they'll get "lol, banzor"-ed.

Answer (score 4):

Try using **java.util.BitSet**

```
public void countUp(int start, int end){
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
    bitSet.set(start, end + 1);
    System.out.println(bitSet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recusion, something alone the lines of:

```
void countUp(int start, int end) {
    //Recursive Case 
    if(start <= end) {
        start += 1;
        countUp(start,end);
        //do some operations
    }
    //Base Case 
    else {
        //we have reached the end 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void countUp(int start, int end)
{
    System.out.println(start);
    if (start < end)
    {
        countUp(start+1, end);
    }
}
```

This should work,

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an exercise to get you to use recursion and not mess around with `java.util.BitSet`, so you could use something like I have below:

```
public class RecursionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 5;
        countUp(start, end); //calls your class countUp
    }

    public static void countUp(int start, int end) {
        System.out.println(start); //prints out start

        if (start < end){ //will run if start is less than end
            countUp(start+1, end); //calls countUp recurses it with start set to start + 1
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!